# CiviCRM User Summit Sept 2016 - Any last minute ideas on how to convince another 20 people to register

Tags: community

CiviCRM User Summit - Any last minute ideas on how to convince another 20 people to register?

The Summit is September 24 & 25  See: https://civicrmusersummit.org/

What would make you want to come?

Comment: I wish I could go! Is there a way to remotely attend sessions? that might make me register.

Comment: Hi pkeogan, that's a good question, but in the wrong place I'd say. What about the forum for this discussion?

Answer (score 2):

I received a somewhat clever promotion from DonorDrive yesterday to encourage behavior.

They were looking for survey respondents- anyone who filled out the survey within 25 minutes got an instant Starbucks gift certificate for $5 (printable).

I don't even like Starbucks, and I fell for it.

Maybe you could use this technique somehow?

Comment: Incentives are known to work. For CiviCRM, the $5 is negligible in comparison to the registration fee. For the registrant, it's a free gift and everyone likes gifts. :)